# ruby merge array of hashes based on the key and order it by number of key/value pair

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have this array of hashes:

```
ah = [{"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "countdown 7"=>1}, {"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "voice 6"=>1},     
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 1"=>1}, {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 2"=>0},     
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 3"=>1}, {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 4"=>0},    
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 5"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 6"=>0},     
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "voice 5"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "voice 6"=>0},    
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-20", "countdown 5"=>1}, {"Date"=>"2014-03-20", "voice 7"=>0},     
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-20", "voice 6"=>0}]
```

and i want to merge it based on the key to have :

```
ah = [{"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "countdown 7"=>1, "voice 6"=>1},      
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 1"=>1, "voice 2"=>0, "voice 3"=>1, "voice 4"=>0, "voice 5"=>0, "voice 6"=>0},       
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "voice 5"=>0, "voice 6"=>0},       
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-20", "countdown 5"=>1, "voice 7"=>0, "voice 6"=>0}]
```

Tried :

```
ah.inject { |all, h| all.merge(h) } #no success
```

Any hints on how to do that?

**update**
Would it be possible to sort it by number of key/value pair? So that the hash that have the most key/value be the first and the one that has the least key value be last?

Output

```
[{"Date"=>"2014-03-18", "voice 1"=>1, "voice 2"=>0, "voice 3"=>1, "voice 4"=>0, "voice 5"=>0, "voice 6"=>0},   
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-20", "countdown 5"=>1, "voice 7"=>0, "voice 6"=>0},
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "countdown 7"=>1, "voice 6"=>1},              
 {"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "voice 5"=>0, "voice 6"=>0}       
]
```

** Update 2 **
To sort the array of hashes by lenght of key/value pair:

```
ah.sort {|a, b| a.length <=> b.length}.reverse
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do :

```
ah.group_by { |h| h['Date'] }.map { |_,v| v.inject(:update) }
# => [{"Date"=>"2014-03-17", "countdown 7"=>1, "voice 6"=>1},
#     {"Date"=>"2014-03-18",
#      "voice 1"=>1,
#      "voice 2"=>0,
#      "voice 3"=>1,
#      "voice 4"=>0,
#      "voice 5"=>0,
#      "voice 6"=>0},
#     {"Date"=>"2014-03-19", "voice 5"=>0, "voice 6"=>0},
#     {"Date"=>"2014-03-20", "countdown 5"=>1, "voice 7"=>0, "voice 6"=>0}]
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer but i have some duplicate...updating my answer

Comment: @mamesaye I am not getting any duplicates.. although :( I ran on the input you have given in the post.

Comment: @mamesaye I don't think you ran Arup's solution correctly. Copy it over carefully and try again. It should work. It does not give the results you showed in your updated question.

Comment: my bad, accepted the answer. Thanks again, Can you suggest some good links on hashes, please?

Comment: ONE MORE QUESTION...Would it be possible to sort it by number of key/value pair? So that the hash that have the most key/value be the first and the one that has the least key value be last? Udating my question...